# I don't have an Instagram account. Can I still look at users' Instagram photos?

Tags: instagram

I don't plan on joining Instagram any time soon. But I have many friends who use the service and they occasionally ask: "Did you see what John posted yesterday?" I tell them no, and then ask them to link me, at which point they throw their hands in the air and say: "Um how?"

Is there a way for Instagram users to link non-users to specific Instagram photos?

Can non-users find specific user pages without joining Instagram?

Comment: The only way I was able to look Instagram photos was to use any third - party instagram viewer. There are many of them, for example https://dumpor.com/ or https://www.picuki.com/. Just do web search "instagram viewer".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of early November, [you can now view](http://techcrunch.com/2012/11/05/mobile-first-web-second-instagram-finally-lets-users-have-functional-web-profiles/) public Instagram profiles and photos via the web.

ie. http://instagram.com/justinbieber

... should put some of those third-party apps out of business.

Comment: As of today, if you click on the above link and scroll down a bit (wait a few seconds), it stops scrolling and you are blocked by a login wall that looks like this https://i.imgur.com/T3pZdoB.png. Thus my interpretation is that If you don't have an account in instagram, they won't let you see any content at all.   FAIL.

Answer (score 11):

**UPDATE 06/11/2012:** This is now possible “natively” by going to `instagram.com/profile_name`. [Source](http://blog.instagram.com/post/35068144047/announcing-instagram-profiles-on-the-web).

**UPDATE 17/04/2020:** But clicking any picture opens a login popup instead of details

---

Yes, if you know your friend’s Instagram username, you can use [Webstagram](https://www.webstagramsite.com/). Search for his/her username and see his/her photo stream. (E.g.: [Ariana Grande’s photos](https://www.webstagramsite.com/user/arianagrande).) However, note that if the respective user’s profile is set to private, you can’t see the photos. [Source](https://web.archive.org/web/20120506192459/https://help.instagram.com/customer/portal/articles/95735-how-the-news-feed-works).

Comment: True! To elaborate: Simply enter a username for XXXX to view his/her public account activity: http://web.stagram.com/n/XXXX/

Comment: It seems you can only natively view an account for a couple of pages before a popup demands you login now.

Comment: The links in this answer are all dead links as of today. :(

Comment: As of 10/06/2020 my solution below still works (using a browser extension)

Answer (score 7):

Webstagram has a little delay, of an hour or two. I use [Statigram](http://statigr.am/).

> Statigram is a web viewer for your Instagram photos. Join Statigram for terrific statistics about your account and tools to manage your community.

Comment: As of today, that Statigram link turns into a login wall: https://i.imgur.com/UI4F3sK.png

Comment: Site no longer exists.

Answer (score 1):

**As of Dec 2021** You can use bibliogram e.g. https://bibliogram.art/u/canditotraininghq

In particular, I use the [redirector extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redirector/ocgpenflpmgnfapjedencafcfakcekcd) with the following rule:

[image: redirector config]

In text form:

```
Insta2Biblio
Redirect:   https://www.instagram.com/*
to: https://bibliogram.art/u/$1
```

This way, whenever you click an instagram link from your browser, you get the bibliogram instance, for example:
[image: bibliogram example]

**Limitation:** You can only load the last 12 pics/vids. If you want to read why, [here's more info](https://proxy.vulpes.one/gemini/cadence.moe/gemlog/2020-12-17-future-of-bibliogram.bliz).

(doesn't work anymore) **As of May 2020** the only way I can access content on a desktop without logging in is this [browser extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/extension-for-instagram/dkfmiibnoifcbiblibjpfalbdfpdoeni) (tested with Opera). I tried all other options, but none of them work anymore after Instagram's latest push of forcing login to see any pics/videos.

[image]

Comment: Does not work on desktop in Chromium. Login screen appears after several reloads of the user page.

Comment: @ks1322 updated the latest working solution

Comment: Probably worth to post new solution as a separate answer.