# View users' Tumblr/Instagram pages without logging in

Tags: tumblr, profile, instagram

A client asked me to add links to their Tumblr and Instagram accounts on their websites. Trouble is I have no idea how to find them and no idea what their URLs are (or even, in Instagram's case, if it's possible).

There are no search boxes on either site. Googling the issue I am told to go to `tumblr.com/search` but this appears as a blank page for me.

Does anyone know how to find users profiles on these sites?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to view a Tumblr account without logging in, all you need is the username/url (which you don't have). There isn't a search option to search by user other than a Google Search

```
site:tumblr.com "query of words associated with your client's blog"
```

For Instagram see: [I don't have an Instagram account. Can I still look at users' Instagram photos?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/28445/i-dont-have-an-instagram-account-can-i-still-look-at-users-instagram-photos)