# is there any other way to signup and access instagram via PC?

Tags: instagram

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I don’t have an Instagram account. Can I still look at users' Instagram photos?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/28445/i-dont-have-an-instagram-account-can-i-still-look-at-users-instagram-photos)

we know that access to instagram only with mobile app, but i want to  signup and access instagram in my PC.

can we access via simulator or VM? or other similar way?

**i have the [eclips](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html) software can i do that? by eclips simulator?**

Comment: Define "access". You can always go to http://instagram.com/<username>

Comment: Please do not remove the duplicate link from the top of the post. You can make any other edit but not that.